# Get a handle to IFileDialog from a TFileDialogEvent to get the filename

Tags: delphi

I am building a TFileSaveDialog descendent component.  The descendent has a PushButton who's event is handled by:

```
function TFileDialogEvent.OnButtonClicked(const pfdc: IFileDialogCustomize;
  dwIDCtl: DWORD): HResult; stdcall;
var
  iImageEnIO: TImageEnIO;
  iFilename: string;
  iName: PChar;
  pfd: IFileDialog;
begin
  if dwIDCtl = dwVisualGroup8ID then
  begin
    iImageEnIO := TImageEnIO.Create(nil);
    try
      FileDialog.QueryInterface(
    StringToGUID('{8016B7B3-3D49-4504-A0AA-2A37494E606F}'),
    pfd);
    // How to get correct valid handle to IFileDialog?
      pfd.GetFileName(iName);
      iFilename := string(iName);
      if FileExists(iFilename) then
      begin
```

The component also displays image information in various control labels correctly.  The component sucessfully returns the selected filename and allows changing folders, but the getting the filename from pfd.GetFileName(iName) in the OnButtonClicked event is returning an invalid filename.  I think the problem is caused by not getting the correct handle for pfd: IFileDialog.

**UPDATE:**
I solved this by defining 
  FileDialog: IFileDialog as a var at the component level then I called

```
function TFileDialogEvent.OnButtonClicked(const pfdc: IFileDialogCustomize;
  dwIDCtl: DWORD): HResult; stdcall;
var
  iImageEnIO: TImageEnIO;
  iFilename: string;
  pFolder: PWideChar;
  iFolder: string;
  iName: PChar;
  pfd: IFileDialog;
  hr: HRESULT;
  aShellItem: IShellItem;
begin
  if dwIDCtl = dwVisualGroup8ID then
  begin
    iImageEnIO := TImageEnIO.Create(nil);
    try
      FileDialog.QueryInterface(IFileDialog, pfd);
      pfd.GetFileName(iName);
      // Get the ShellItem
      hr := SHCreateItemFromParsingName(iName, nil,
      StringToGUID(SID_IShellItem), aShellItem);
      // Get the folder
      pfd.GetFolder(aShellItem);
      // Get the folder displayname
      aShellItem.GetDisplayName(SIGDN_FILESYSPATH, pFolder);
      iFolder := string(pFolder);
      if DirectoryExists( iFolder) then
        iFilename := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter( iFolder) + string(iName);
      if FileExists(iFilename) then
      begin
```

Thank-you all... Thank-you Rob... your post was helpful.

Comment: you should replace
      FileDialog.QueryInterface(IFileDialog, pfd);
with
      pfd := FileDialog as IFileDialog;

Comment: The code in your updated question is pointless. FileDialog is already IFileDialog. And Rob's solution also works so no need for that extra field anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're querying the object for an interface matching the GUID {8016B7B3-3D49-4504-A0AA-2A37494E606F}, and storing the result in an `IFileDialog` reference. The problem is that {8016B7B3-3D49-4504-A0AA-2A37494E606F} is the GUID for the `IFileDialogCustomize` interface, not `IFileDialog`. You attempt to call `GetFileName`, which is the sixth method of the `IFileDialog` interface, but since the variable actually holds an `IFileDialogCustomize` interface, control ends up being transferred to the sixth function of *that* interface instead. The compiler cannot catch the type mismatch for you, partly because you're constructing the GUID dynamically at run time (so it doesn't know the value at compile time), and partly because the second parameter to `QueryInterface` is untyped (so it can't know that the type of the variable is supposed to match the first parameter).

There's an easier way than computing the GUID at run time. Interface types are *automatically* useable as their associated GUIDs (when they have GUIDs). To request the `IFileDialog` interface, just pass that identifier directly to `QueryInterface`:

```
FileDialog.QueryInterface(IFileDialog, pfd);
```

You don't even have to call `QueryInterface` if you use the `as` operator:

```
pfd := FileDialog as IFileDialog;
```

When you call `QueryInterface` directly, you need to make sure you check the result for error codes. If you use the `as` operator, an unsupported interface will raise an exception. If you just want pass-fail without too much error checking, use the `Supports` function instead:

```
if Supports(FileDialog, IFileDialog, pfd) then ...
```

Comment: Whoops...FileDialog is not defined in the function TFileDialogEvent.OnButtonClicked event... How is it defined here?

Comment: Don't ask me. *You're* the one who pasted it into your question.

Comment: I guess that is why it did not work for me... If FileDialog is not defined in the function TFileDialogEvent is it still possible?

Comment: It's becoming clear to me that you didn't really copy and paste your real code. Where your question calls `QueryInterface` on a variable named `FileDialog`, I suspect your *code* calls it on a variable named `pfdc`, matching the name of the parameter in the function declaration. You came here with a *runtime* problem. If you have a compile-time problem now (undeclared identifier), you should know that there's no way it could have been the cause of your run-time problem. The compile-time problem is one you introduced by posting fake code here.

Comment: it was not fake code... the problem was I changed it too many times while trying to get it to work... meanwhile I worked around the problem by storing the filename as a string in the OnSelectionChange(const pfd: IFileDialog) so that the filename would be available in the TFileDialogEvent.

Answer (score 0):

`TSaveFileDialog` has a public `Dialog` property of type `IFileDialog`, so you don't need to hunt for it manually, you already have direct access to it, eg:

```
function TFileDialogEvent.OnButtonClicked(const pfdc: IFileDialogCustomize;  dwIDCtl: DWORD): HResult; stdcall; 
var 
  iImageEnIO: TImageEnIO; 
  iFilename: string; 
  iName: PWideChar; 
begin 
  if dwIDCtl <> dwVisualGroup8ID then
    Result := E_NOTIMPL
  else
  begin
    Result := S_OK;
    if FAILED(Self.Dialog.GetFileName(iName)) then Exit;
    try 
      iFilename := string(iName); 
    finally
      CoTaskMemFree(iName);
    end;
    iImageEnIO := TImageEnIO.Create(nil); 
    try 
      if FileExists(iFilename) then 
      begin 
        ...
      end;
    finally
      iImageEnIO.Free;
    end; 
  end;
end;
```

Comment: TFileDialogEvent is the class that implements the advised events rather than the class that implements the dialog.